# Sending Multiple Attachments firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying send a email with multiple attachments, but, in Android SDK most recent, was changed the method to send files, and most existing tutorials is about the older SDK version ...

I obtained send the email with only one attachment, but not with multiple...

I try using the same method of 1 attachment but using it twice. Not works, the delphi catch only the last `Intent.putExtra`.

What I'm making wrong ?

(Utilizing only the Android Plataform)

```
procedure TF_inicio.Rec_exportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sfilename: string;

  AttachmentFile1: JFile;
  AttachmentFile2: JFile;
  AttachmentFile3: JFile;

  Intent: JIntent;
  AddressesTo, Anexos: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  I: Integer;
  LSearchOption: TSearchOption;
  // AddressesCC, AddressesBCC: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
begin
  LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(path, '*.csv', LSearchOption);

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SENDTO);
  Intent.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('mailto:')));
  AddressesTo := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1); // Enviar para:
  AddressesTo.Items[0] := StringToJString('MyEmail@gmail.com');
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, AddressesTo);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    StringToJString(F_inicio.placa_veiculo + ' - ' +
    FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM', NOW)));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT,
    StringToJString('Email automático' + sLineBreak + ''));

  if Length(LList) = 1 then
    AttachmentFile1 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[1]));

  if Length(LList) = 2 then
    AttachmentFile2 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[2]));

  if Length(LList) = 3 then
    AttachmentFile3 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[3]));

  if Length(LList) >= 1 then
  begin
    AttachmentFile1 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[1]));
    Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM,
      TJParcelable.Wrap((TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile1)
      as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));
  end;

  if Length(LList) >= 2 then
  begin
    AttachmentFile2 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[2]));
    Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM,
      TJParcelable.Wrap((TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile2)
      as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));
  end;

  if Length(LList) >= 3 then
  begin
    AttachmentFile3 := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[3]));
    Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM,
      TJParcelable.Wrap((TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile3)
      as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));
  end;

  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: You have *if Length(LList) = 1 then* when it should be *if Length(LList) >= 1 then*. Same with the other lines that follow.

Comment: Just use a simple loop to add the attachments, all those redundant `if` blocks are unnecessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send multiple attachments using Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332750/)

Comment: The problem is in the method that is done, it should work, but it takes only the last intention

Comment: @RemyLebeau not duplicated because sdk updates

Comment: @user3602803 and what updates are you referring to exactly? You need to be more specific

Comment: @RemyLebeau What I need is to attach all files of a folder, this code I posted works but it only takes the last attachment, ie I am rewriting one attachment with the other. I was wondering if there is any way this won't happen, of actually attaching multiple attachments

Comment: There are only text files in the folder. Their extension is .csv

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple loop to add the attachments, all those redundant if blocks are unnecessary:

```pascal
procedure TF_inicio.Rec_exportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sfilename: string;
  AttachmentFile: JFile;
  Intent: JIntent;
  AddressesTo, Anexos: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  I: Integer;
  LSearchOption: TSearchOption;
  // AddressesCC, AddressesBCC: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  LUri: Jnet_URI;
begin
  LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(path, '*.csv', LSearchOption);

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SENDTO);
  Intent.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('mailto:')));
  AddressesTo := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1); // Enviar para:
  AddressesTo.Items[0] := StringToJString('MyEmail@gmail.com');
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, AddressesTo);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    StringToJString(F_inicio.placa_veiculo + ' - ' +
    FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM', NOW)));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT,
    StringToJString('Email automático' + sLineBreak + ''));

  for I := 0 to Length(LList)-1 do
  begin
    AttachmentFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[I]));
    LUri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile);
    Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, TJParcelable.Wrap((LUri as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));
  end;

  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Or, use a single call to `Intent.putExtra(Parsable[])` or `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()` to add an array of URIs, instead of calling `Intent.putExtra(Parsable)` for each individual URI:

```pascal
procedure TF_inicio.Rec_exportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  LSearchOption: TSearchOption;
  Intent: JIntent;
  I: Integer;
  AttachmentFile: JFile;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
  LURIs: TJavaObjectArray<JParcelable>;
begin
  LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(path, '*.csv', LSearchOption);

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
  Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  Intent.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('mailto:')));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, StringToJString('MyEmail@gmail.com'));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(F_inicio.placa_veiculo + ' - ' + FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM', NOW)));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('Email automático' + sLineBreak + ''));

  if LList <> nil then
  begin
    LURIs := TJavaObjectArray<JParcelable>.Create(Length(LList));
    for I := 0 to Length(LList)-1 do
    begin
      AttachmentFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[I]));
      LUri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile);
      LURIs[I] := TJParcelable.Wrap((LUri as ILocalObject).GetObjectID); 
    end;
    Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, LURIs);
  end;

  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

```pascal
procedure TF_inicio.Rec_exportClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  LSearchOption: TSearchOption;
  Intent: JIntent;
  I: Integer;
  AttachmentFile: JFile;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
  LURIs: JArrayList;
begin
  LSearchOption := TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly;
  LList := TDirectory.GetFiles(path, '*.csv', LSearchOption);

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
  Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  Intent.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('mailto:')));
  Intent.setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, StringToJString('MyEmail@gmail.com'));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(F_inicio.placa_veiculo + ' - ' + FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM', NOW)));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString('Email automático' + sLineBreak + ''));

  if LList <> nil then
  begin
    LURIs := TJArrayList.Create;
    for I := 0 to Length(LList)-1 do
    begin
      AttachmentFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(LList[I]));
      LUri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile);
      LURIs.add(LUri); 
    end;
    Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, LURIs);
  end;

  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: I tested these 3 codes and they all result in different errors, first code error: `There is no overloaded version of 'putExtra' that can be called with these arguments`
line: `Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, LURIs);`

Comment: second code error: `There is no overloaded version of 'Wrap' that can be called with these arguments`
line: `Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, TJParcelable.Wrap(LUri as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));`

Comment: third code error (in app):
`android.os.FileUriExposedException:
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Locale_Externo/AAA9189%2012.08.2019%2020.12.59.csv exposed beyond through ClipData.Item.getUri()`

Comment: Can you tell me why these errors happened? Oh, in the third code, a file path appeared, but there are several files in that same folder (about 2kb each), so I don't know why there was only one

Comment: @user3602803 I updated my answer to address the 1st and 2nd errors. As for the 3rd error, you can't use "file://" URIs in an `Intent` to share files with other apps anymore when targeting SDK 24 or higher, you now need to use "content://" URIs from the `FileProvider` class, see [Sharing Files](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) in Android's documentation. You will have to update your code accordingly. I don't have a Delphi example to give you right now